# Unable To Install React.js || "Use controlled folder access in windows" error occurred

Tags: visual-studio-code, create-react-app, npx, controlled-folder-access

I Am Trying To Install React App Using npx create-react-app myapp but use controlled access error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I Was Installing React app but When I Was Writing the npx create-react-app myapp command , "folder controlled access" error occurred.
so the solution is very Easy you just have to grant permission.

1.Select **Start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection.**

2.Under **Virus & threat protection settings**, select **Manage settings**.
Under **Controlled folder access**, select **Manage Controlled folder access.**
3.Switch the Controlled folder access setting to **On or Off**.

Occasionally, an app that is safe to use will be identified as harmful. This happens because Microsoft wants to keep you safe and will sometimes err on the side of caution; however, this might interfere with how you normally use your PC. You can add an app to the list of safe or allowed apps to prevent them from being blocked.